# how to add a custom column in matrix power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am fairly new to power bi and I am creating a matrix table, I made this:

[image: matrix]

I know there is an option to add total column to the table, but is there a way to add a column that has the average of the rows ? I want to add a custom column that takes the average of the rows in this matrix, is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has been asked before and answered in this way.I am sending you 2 separate links.  Good works

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Matrix-Average-Column/m-p/2388259

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-change-total-column-sum-to-average-in-matrix/m-p/61633